# CIFS only share owner may delete files in share root

Tags: linux, samba, cifs

gI was installing myself samba on a minimalist fork of ubuntu (linux-lite).

At first I installed it without any user managment, and only a guest account, here is my smb.conf

```
[global]
workgroup=WORKGROUP
server string = Test NAS
netbios name = testsan
security = user
encrypt password = true
map to guest = bad user
guest account = smbguest
dns proxy = no

[smb]
path = /smb/
available = yes
browsable = yes
writeable = yes
guest ok = yes
printable = no
create mask = 0664
directory mask = 0775
```

The linux user smbguest has "smbusers" as his main group

here is the local file :
    drwxrwxr-x 2 root smbusers 4096 Aug  1 11:00 /smb/

When i mount it as cifs or access to it from a windows host, i am able to create,rename and delete directories
I am able to create & edit files, but not rename or delete files in share root, even if i just created them and am their owner.
Just like if i had no "write" access to the folder... but i do, since if i `su - smbguest` and do it from there i can.

This seems somehow related to CIFS ACLs, would someone be able to explain ?

Comment: have you noticed that 'guest ok=yes', is misspelled in your shares section? since all your users are working under the smbguest account, that could be significant.

Comment: Sorry i rewrote it by hand since i couldn't copy from my Virtual Machine. it is spelled right there.